# How to use IRequiresRequest to inject IRequest in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack, httpcontext

I need to access request context, specifically the Items inside my custom class and I don't want to do have it either inheriting from `ServiceStack` Service or having the set it up inside the my Service.

So if I have a class like below which the implementer class (`ContextItemsGetter`) also implements `IRequiresRequest`, I would expect the `Request` property to be populated.

```
public interface IGetContextItems
{
  string Get(string key);
}

public class ContextItemsGetter : IGetContextItems, IRequiresRequest
{
  public string Get(string key)
  {
    //someway to access http context items
    //im RequestContext.Instance.Items[key] e.g. Prop1 Prop2
    //or Request.blah but Request is always null
  }
  public IRequest Request { get; set; }
}
```

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IRequiresRequest.cs

However the Request is always null for both when SessionIdGetter is called from a genuine **HTTP request** or a **redis message request**. Am I doing something wrong? The purpose is to decouple and use Items to pass information between http request and redis message request.

I've also tried to use RequestContext.Instance.Items, where this worked for HTTP request, but during redis message request, the items are not there, the keys where I populated just before calling ExecuteMessage are not there.

```
    var req = new BasicRequest { Verb = HttpMethods.Get };

    req.Items.Add("Prop1", m.GetBody().Prop1);
    req.Items.Add("Prop2", m.GetBody().Prop2);

    var result = HostContext.ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(m, req);
```

I'm using version 4.0.50.

Also, this page [Access HTTP specific features in services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Access-HTTP-specific-features-in-services) where mentions

> Note: `ServiceStack`'s Service base class already implements `IRequiresRequestContext` which allows you to access the `IRequestContext` with `base.RequestContext` and the HTTP Request and Response with `base.Request` and `base.Response`.

I believe `IRequiresRequestContext` is now called `IRequiresRequest`, so I think the doc should be updated.

> **Updated:** **full code to demo my original intention:**

```
    [Route("/test", Verbs = "GET")]
    public class Dto : IReturnVoid
    { }

    public class DtoService : Service
    {
        //So that IGetContextItems is taken care of by IDependencyThatUsesIGetContextItems
        public IDependencyThatUsesIGetContextItems DependencyThatUsesIGetContextItems { get; set; }

        public void Get(Dto req)
        {
            DependencyThatUsesIGetContextItems.SomeMethod();
        }
    }

    public interface IGetContextItems
    {
        string Get(string key);
    }
    //since ContextItemsGetter implmeents IRequiresRequest
    //I can still easily test any service that uses IGetContextItems by mocking IGetContextItems
    public class ContextItemsGetter : IGetContextItems, IRequiresRequest
    {
        public IRequest Request { get; set; }

        public string Get(string key)
        {
            //either through injection
            //return Request.Items[key].ToString();

            //or some static class
            //return RequestContext.RequestItems.Items[key].ToString();
            return RequestContext.Instance.Items[key].ToString();
        }
    }

    public interface IDependencyThatUsesIGetContextItems
    {
        string SomeMethod();
    }
    public class DependencyThatUsesIGetContextItems : IDependencyThatUsesIGetContextItems
    {
        //this will be inejcted
        public IGetContextItems ContextItemsGetter { get; set; }

        public string SomeMethod()
        {
            var a = ContextItemsGetter.Get("SomeKey");
            return "blah";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IRequiresRequest` only injects the current `IRequest` to your **Service** classes and **Validation Filters**, it doesn't inject the IRequest into your dependencies which are resolved directly from the IOC and who doesn't have access to current IRequest to be able to inject.

Also ServiceStack's convenient `Service` and `AbstractValidator<T>`  base classes already implement `IRequiresRequest` so in most cases the places where `IRequiresRequest` applies has already been implemented so you shouldn't need to implement it yourself.

The recommended approach to passing the `IRequest` into your dependencies is to pass them as a parameter from your Service, e.g:

```cs
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public IGetContextItems ContextItems { get; set; }

    public object Get(Request request)
    {
       return ContextItems.Get(base.Request, request.Id);
    }
}
```

You do have an opportunity to inspect and modify your Service instance before it executes your Service by overriding `OnPreExecuteServiceFilter()` in your AppHost to go through and inject the `IRequest` in each of your Services dependencies that implement `IRequiresRequest` with:

```cs
public override object OnPreExecuteServiceFilter(IService service, 
    object request, IRequest req, IResponse res)
{
    service.InjectRequestIntoDependencies(req);
    return request;
}
```

Which calls the below extension method will recursively populate your Services dependency graph as long as each parent implements `IRequiresRequest`:

```cs
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
    public static void InjectRequestIntoDependencies(this object instance, IRequest req)
    {
        foreach (var pi in instance.GetType().GetPublicProperties())
        {
            var mi = pi.GetGetMethod();
            if (mi == null)
                continue;

            var dep = mi.Invoke(instance, new object[0]);
            var requiresRequest = dep as IRequiresRequest;
            if (requiresRequest != null)
            {
                requiresRequest.Request = req;
                requiresRequest.InjectRequestIntoDependencies(req);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you need to be careful to not implement `IRequiresRequest` on any of your Singleton dependencies (the default scope) as it's not ThreadSafe whereas passing IRequest as a parameter would be.

Also to avoid coupling your logic classes to ServiceStack I'd consider only passing in what your dependencies needs from `IRequest` instead of the `IRequest` instance itself which will also make it easier to test.

Comment: thanks again for the quick and detailed response. I updated the question to show my full intention. My original intention was to not having to setup the two interfaces (dependencies IGetContextItems and IDependencyThatUsesIGetContextItems) inside DtoService/Get method (if possible at all). Because if I have 1000 services I would have to repeat many times, or I have to have an abstract CustomClass which does the setting up and all other services inherit from CustomClass.
I'll exam your suggestion and make a decision, but I guess it's probably best to go by the recommended way.

Comment: @Jeff FYI I've modified my example to recursively populate `IRequest` in your Services dependency graph as long as each parent implements `IRequiresRequest`.

Comment: that's what I was going to do as well, thanks! I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is a good way or not, basically I want to be decoupled from Service as much as possible, but then the argument goes, I'll get miserable runtime errors cos dependencies which rely on Context sometime can fail when not run within the "correct context (ie http context).

Comment: @Jeff right if you try to access the RequestContext singleton outside of the context of a HTTP Request (e.g. in a background thread) it will be null, but passing the `IRequest` parameter wont be. But trying to decouple your logic classes from the Service is another reason why you should only consider passing in what you need from IRequest and not the full instance.

Comment: fully understood. and all my dependecies are per request scope. thanks